# Boolean algebra -- minterms for 1:1 inputs and outputs

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let's say we have a truth table with two inputs (`A`, `B`) and one output (`X`).

| `A` | `B` | `X` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `0` |
| `0` | `1` | `1` |
| `1` | `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `1` | `0` |

I know that I can write a boolean function by (a) choosing rows where `X` is `1`, (b) writing the *minterms* for these lines and (c) write *cannonical sum of products* (CSOP) like this:
$$
F(A,B) = (\overline{A}\cdot B) + (A \cdot \overline{B})
$$

---

But how do we use the same principle if there is only one input (`A`) and one output (`X`) i.e.:

| `A` | `X` |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `0` |

Does *minterm* even exist in this example?

---

Or maybe even this (`X` is constantly `0`):

| `A` | `X` |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` |
| `1` | `0` |

> *Note:*
> I want the correct mathematical derivation of these simple examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the true answer is:

We first write the short minterm form of a boolean function for *"ones" (where X = 1)* of the truth table:

$$
X(A) = \sum m(0) 
$$

In this case we only have one minterm i.e

$$
m_0 = \overline{A}
$$

So we can simply write:

$$
X(A) = m_0\\
\boxed{X(A) = \overline{A}}
$$

---

For the other example we can simmilarly write the short minterm form of the boolean function for *"zeroes" (where X = 0)*:

$$
\overline{X}(A) = \sum m(0,1) 
$$

In this case we have two minterms i.e

$$
m_0 = \overline{A}\\
m_1 = A
$$

So we can simply write:

$$
\overline{X}(A) = m_0 + m_1\\
\overline{X}(A) = \overline{A} + A\\
\overline{X}(A) = 1\\
\boxed{X(A) = 0}
$$

This is the correct derivation.

---

Principles described here are from the book:

> *"Fundamentals of digital electronics and computer design with VHDL (Sandige)"*, chapter 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "correct mathematical derivation" but by inspection for your second case:
\$X = \overline{A}\$

and for your third case:
\$X = 0\$

Comment: Yeah I know this... But how do you handle the minterms in these scenarios? I am questioning the minterms method and I am questioning it is not quite universal *(does not work for 1 input)*.

Comment: Maybe elaborate more on your confusion? In my eyes, you are using the same method to  get the correct answer. "Choose rows where X is 1". Okay, so select the first row and write the equation: Not A. There is no B column so B can't possibly be part of the equation. There are no more rows where X is 1, so we're done: it's already minimized. For constant zero: "Choose rows where X is 1". There aren't any, so X is always zero. All done.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was curious about the mind process that you clearly showed me.